# Is there a way to know if a Task is being awaited?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a method

```
public Task<Task> DoSomeWorkOnARemoteMachine()
```

which, very descriptively, executes some work on a remote machine by:

1. Queueing a message on a message bus signalling that work should be done
2. A remote agent picks up the message and executes the work
3. The work finishes and the agent queues a message on a message bus to say that the work is done
4. The application which invoked the work picks up the message that the work is done

The reason I used `Task<Task>` is because the first `Task<>` is for the queueing of the message; while the inner `Task` is completed when the work has been completed on the remote machine (i.e. when the message from the agent has been received). Any exceptions which the remote agent caught during execution of the work are passed along with the completion message and are re-thrown when the inner `Task` completes.

To call this method I use:

```
await await DoSomeWorkOnARemoteMachine();
```

which would wait for the message to be queued to execute the job, as well as to complete the job and receive any exceptions. However, if I was not interested in whether the job completed on the remote agent or not, I might call it as follows:

```
await DoSomeWorkOnARemoteMachine();
```

which would not `await` the inner `Task`. However, the inner `Task` (which receives the message from the remote agent, and re-throws the exceptions) would still execute at some point. I feel that this is a bit of a waste and I would like to avoid executing it when I don't `await` for the results.

My question is thus: is it possible for a `Task` to "know" whether it is being `await`ed and not execute if it is not, or execute some other code path (such as an empty `Task` body).

I do realize that there are alternatives that I could implement, such as passing a "fire and forget" flag, or adding an overload for "fire and forget". It would be great though if I could implement this without the client API changing

Answers involving other projects which implement this sort of remote work execution would also be great!

Comment: You almost certainly wouldn't *want* to do this, even if you could.  What if the continuations are added to that task down the road, rather than right away.  They'll now never run because the task will never finish.  It's actually reasonably common to stick tasks into a data structure or field and then add continuations later; this would make all of them break, but in a very confusing and hard to debug manor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you're doing this is quite confusing. It's not clear at all what the `Task<Task>` is supposed to mean. What I would do instead is to make your method return something like `Task<Work>`. The `Work` type would then have a method like `GetResultAsync()`, which would return the `Task` that represents the execution of the work on the remote machine.

This way, you have code that has much clearer meaning and you can also easily recognize whether to process the response, based on whether `GetResultAsync()` was called or not.

Comment: I actually quite like that approach. It is much cleaner

Comment: I eventually went with this approach. While the other answers helped, this answer gave me a great direction which I appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

That is a very interesting question. Yet, if I understood it correctly, I believe this is impossible, in the way you presented it, because it doesn't make sense (IMO). Let's look at the following model (please let me know if I got it wrong):

```
static async Task<Task> DoSomeWorkOnARemoteMachine()
{
    // Point X: 
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    // Point Y: 
    Console.WriteLine("request sent");
    var taskInner = Task.Delay(2000);
    // Point A: here you want to know if there's an await at Point B
    return taskInner;
}

static async Task Test()
{
    var taskOuter = DoWorkAsync();
    // Point Z: 
    await taskOuter;
    // Point B: 
    await taskOuter.Result; // await taskInner
    Console.WriteLine("request received");
}
```

At the **Point A**, you like to know if there's an `await` at the **Point B**. But at this moment, the **Point B** is still in the future, it hasn't happened yet. You'd need a time machine for that :)

**[UPDATE]** In the same way, at the **Point X** you cannot know about the `await` at the **Point Z**, because the code flow has not reached **Z** yet.

However, when at **Y**, in theory you possibly *could* know about the `await` at **Z** (still not about **B**). Although, I don't know if it's technically possible to get a hold of such information.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think it's easily or efficiently achievable (playing with Task.GetAwaiter is a bad idea, and it will not be accessible from inside your function, see Noseratio's answer). Here is alternative solutions :

Solution n°1 : Function parameter for `Task` execution

```
await DoSomeWorkOnARemoteMachine(false) //Indicates that DoSomeWork shouldn't be executed
```

Solution n°2 : Explicit Task Execution

```
Task t = await DoSomeWorkOnARemoteMachine() ;
t.Start(); // For example, if you want to execute the resulting Task. 
           // You can also dispatch it to an other thread, etc...
```

Comment: +1, a `bool` argument like that is a natural way to instruct the logic inside the outer task to not start the inner task, and return `Task.FromResult` (or `null`) instead.

Comment: A `Task` that has to be `Start()`ed doesn't make much sense, especially since it means it would have to block.